# cakephp routing views within sub directory

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How do I connect to a view in a subfolder in cakephp 1.3?
If I organize folders in my Views like:

> Views/my_folder/my_subfolder/mypage.ctp

How do I connect to the mypage.ctp view in routes? I've tried the following:

```
Router::connect('/my_folder/my_subfolder/mypage',
array('controller' => 'my_folder', 'action' => 'mypage'));
```

The above does not work. Is there a different way to write the connection in routes.php?

I want the url to be: www.mysite.com/my_folder/my_subfolder

Comment: I can get the url I want but I really wanted to be able to nest (organize sub-folders) in my Views folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Pages` controller looks for views in `Views/Pages`
so move your `mypage.ctp` there.

The structure of `Views` folder is guided by conventions, mapping from url to controller+action is the only thing that you change via routes.

Comment: Well, let's say I make a controller called, my_folder and write function mypage()...

Comment: Well, let's say I make a controller called, my_folder and write function mypage()...then my route has to be: Router::connect('/my_folder/mypage',
    array('controller' => 'my_folder', 'action' => 'mypage')
);   this requires me to place mypage.ctp into the 'my_folder" when I'd like to place it in 'my_subfolder'.  Router::connect('/my_folder/my_subfolder/mypage',
    array('controller' => 'my_folder', 'action' => 'mypage'));  is what I tried but it doesn't connect.

Comment: structure of Views folder is given by conventions, the structure is just two levels deep: `Views/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]`

if you deliberately choose not to follow it, than you have to call
`$this->render('subfolder/mypage')` at the end of the action by yourself

Comment: please refer to the book for all the details: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions

if you just want the url to be `www.mysite.com/my_folder/my_subfolder/mypage` stick to your original route and to the Pages controller and just move the `mypage.ctp` to `Views/Pages/mypage.ctp` - that will do

Comment: yeah, I an get the url I want but I really wanted to be able to nest (organize sub-folders) in my Views folder.

Comment: ok, ... than you have to call `$this->render('subfolder/action')` at the end of the action by yourself :)

Comment: so  function myfolder() { $this->render('mysubfolder/mypage') }

Answer (score 0):

Please check it

Router::connect( '/foldername', array('controller' => 'controllername', 'action' => 'functionname'));